# Which Attribute from System Template is Functional Destination Address for DCMIPdu in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

In AUTOSAR System Template for 4-4, I find the following and I am looking for more clarity about which Table in System Template defines this "Functional Destination Address". Some hints please.
[image: AUTOSAR DCMIPdu]

Comment: You should finf out the `TpConnection` which references the `DcmIPdu` in the `TpConnection.tpSdu` and which has the `TpConnection.taType == FUNCTIONAL` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUTOSAR classic platform does not actively use a "diagnostic address". The routing of diagnostic messages is typically described using the `TpConnection` for CAN, Lin, FlexRay, and Ethernet.

The last leg of `TpConnections` is further qualified by means of the `DiagnosticConnection` that references `TpConnection` in different roles, such as physical request, functional request, response.

In other words, the `DiagnosticConnection` identifies a bundle of `TpCnnection`s and their role in the diagnostic communication.